# applicationDidBecomeActive from dock vs open document?

Tags: cocoa, document

When I receive applicationDidBecomeActive, is there a way to tell if it is because a document was double clicked in the Finder (or drug to the app icon), vs just having clicked on the Dock icon or selected the app with Cmd-Tab?

I need to know if applicationDidBecomeActive is associated with an openDocument event.

Comment: Why do you want to know? Maybe there's an other solution.

Comment: If the app is already open, but in the background with no files open... If the user pulls it to the foreground without opening a file, I'd like to open a new blank window, but if it came to the foreground because a file was being opened, it should not open a new file.

Comment: A document based app should do this automatically.